# Capitalize the first letter of the first word

Tags: vim

In ViM, how can I transform these lines of text:

```
stringa1 minuscolo
stringa2 minuscolo
stringa33 minuscolo
stringa44 minuscolo
```

into this:

```
Stringa1 minuscolo
Stringa2 minuscolo
Stringa33 minuscolo
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following command will convert(It is a string substitute regex) the first character to uppercase

`:%s/^./\u&/g` will replace first char in all the lines

`:1,4s/^./\u&/g`

This command will replace line starting from 1 to 4 (`1,4`) change the line range in the command.

Answer (score 4):

It's also worth noting the `~` command, which switches the case of the character under the cursor, and the `gU` operator which converts to uppercase across the given motion.  Example:

`gUl` converts the current character to uppercase (or leaves it uppercase if it is already)

`gUe` converts to uppercase through to the end of the word

`g~e` switches the case of each letter through the end of the word.

Try `:help case` for more.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an alternative approach (Linux provides you so many different ways of doing the same thing; ultimately depends on personal choice/preference.)

```
sed -rin 's/./\u&/1p' file.txt
```

Another alternative is below which capitalizes first letter of each word

```
sed -rin 's/([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*)/\u\1\2/g p' file.txt
```